# VLANs and Access Point

Tags: wifi, vlan, pfsense

I have all my network (wired and WiFi) in the same VLAN. I just bought a new Access Point, and am trying to set WiFi Clients to be in VLAN 2.

On the AP, I set it to assign VLAN 2 to the clients, and on my pfSense firewall, I configured a VLAN for WiFi on the same NIC where the LAN is. I also enabled DHCP for the WIFI VLAN, using a different subnet (192.168.2.0/24) than the existing LAN (192.168.0.0/24).

When I connect with a client to WiFi, my client doesn't get an IP address.

The AP is connected to a switch, which is connected to the LAN NIC of the pfSense. As far as I know, those are untagged for VLAN.

I tried restarting pfSense, as I read adding VLANs might require it, but the issue persisted.

My network has two switches. A Baseline Switch 2250-SFP Plus and a Baseline Switch 2226-SFP Plus.

pfSense is plugged to the 2250 in port 3, and port 49 is used to cascade to port 25 of the 2226. The UniFi is plugged to port 17 of the 2226.

I've created the VLAN 2 in both the 2250 and the 2226, and added ports 3 and 49 of the 2250 and 17 and 25 of the 2226 as VLAN 2 tagged.

The UniFi gets its IP address though DHCP, and is only getting an IP address of the wired subnet (which I believe is ok).

I can connect to WiFi just fine, but I can't get an IP address.

Comment: You might want to add the model number of your manageable vlan-capable switch, and its settings for the ports to the AP and pfsense.

Comment: @AlexStragies just added more details on the VLAN configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the port on the switch to accept tagged packets. This is usually accomplished by changing the port mode to trunk.

On the firewall, you also need to set up packets for that subnet to be tagged as VLAN 2, and you will need to set the switch port mode to trunk. On some firewalls, you actually create a new virtual interface for the VLAN. I have no experience with pfSense, so I can't help you there.